# Conditionally fill column based off values in other columns in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause, apply

This question is similar to a few questions regarding conditionally filling of columns but my `df` is a bit more complex.

I have a `df` with columns that contain floats and strings. I'm trying to conditionally fill the column that contains floats based off the strings.

Based on the `df` below:

If the value in `Code` starts with `A`, I want to keep the values as they are.

If the value `Code` starts with `B`, I want to keep the same initial value and return `nan's` to the following rows until the next value in `Code`.

If the value in `Code` starts with `C`, I want to keep the same first value until the next floats in `['Numx','Numy]`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


d = ({                          
      'Code' :['A1','A1','','B1','B1','A2','A2','','B2','B2','','A3','A3','A3','','B1','','B4','B4','A2','A2','A1','A1','','B4','B4','C1','C1','','','D1','','B2'],
      'Numx' : [30.2,30.5,30.6,35.6,40.2,45.5,46.1,48.1,48.5,42.2,'',30.5,30.6,35.6,40.2,45.5,'',48.1,48.5,42.2, 40.1,48.5,42.2,'',48.5,42.2,43.1,44.1,'','','','',45.1],
      'Numy' : [1.9,2.3,2.5,2.2,2.5,3.1,3.4,3.6,3.7,5.4,'',2.3,2.5,2.2,2.5,3.1,'',3.6,3.7,5.4,6.5,8.5,2.2,'',8.5,2.2,2.3,2.5,'','','','',3.2]
      })
```

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

Output:

```
   Code  Numx Numy
0    A1  30.2  1.9
1    A1  30.5  2.3
2        30.6  2.5
3    B1  35.6  2.2
4    B1  40.2  2.5
5    A2  45.5  3.1
6    A2  46.1  3.4
7        48.1  3.6
8    B2  48.5  3.7
9    B2  42.2  5.4
10        nan  nan       
11   A3  30.5  2.3
12   A3  30.6  2.5
13   A3  35.6  2.2
14       40.2  2.5
15   B1  45.5  3.1
16        nan  nan     
17   B4  48.1  3.6
18   B4  48.5  3.7
19   A2  42.2  5.4
20   A2  40.1  6.5
21   A1  48.5  8.5
22   A1  42.2  2.2
23        nan  nan      
24   B4  48.5  8.5
25   B4  42.2  2.2
26   C1  43.1  2.3
27   C1  44.1  2.5
28        nan  nan      
29        nan  nan   
30   D1   nan  nan      
31        nan  nan        
32   B2  45.1  3.2
```

I was thinking something like this when the value in `Code` is `B`:

```
df['Numx'] = np.where(df['Code'] == 'B-'.ffill()) 
df['Numy'] = np.where(df['Code'] == 'B-'.ffill())
```

So my desired output would be:

```
   Code  Numx Numy
0    A1  30.2  1.9
1    A1  30.5  2.3
2        30.6  2.5
3    B1  35.6  2.2
4    B1   nan  nan
5    A2  45.5  3.1
6    A2  46.1  3.4
7        48.1  3.6
8    B2  48.5  3.7
9    B2   nan  nan
10        nan  nan        
11   A3  30.5  2.3
12   A3  30.6  2.5
13   A3  35.6  2.2
14       40.2  2.5
15   B1  45.5  3.1
16        nan  nan         
17   B4  48.1  3.6
18   B4   nan  nan
19   A2  42.2  5.4
20   A2  40.1  6.5
21   A1  48.5  8.5
22   A1  42.2  2.2
23        nan  nan      
24   B4  48.5  8.5
25   B4   nan  nan
26   C1  43.1  2.3
27   C1  43.1  2.3
28       43.1  2.3   
29       43.1  2.3   
30   D1  43.1  2.3   
31       43.1  2.3         
32   B2  45.1  3.2
```

Comment: Is output correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need:

```
df['Code_new'] = df['Code'].where(df['Code'].isin(['AA','BB'])).ffill()

df[['Numx','Numy']] = df[['Numx','Numy']].mask(df['Code_new'].duplicated())
mask = df['Code_new'] == 'BB'
df.loc[mask, ['Numx','Numy']] = df.loc[mask, ['Numx','Numy']].ffill()
print (df)
  Code  Numx Numy Code_new
0   AA  30.2  1.9       AA
1        NaN  NaN       AA
2        NaN  NaN       AA
3   BB  35.6  2.2       BB
4       35.6  2.2       BB
5       35.6  2.2       BB
6       35.6  2.2       BB
7   CC  35.6  2.2       BB
8       35.6  2.2       BB
9   DD  35.6  2.2       BB
```

Or:

```
df = df.replace('nan', np.nan)

df['Code_new'] = df['Code'].where(df['Code'].isin(['AA','BB'])).ffill()

m1 = df['Code_new'].duplicated() & (df['Code_new'] == 'AA')
df[['Numx','Numy']] = df[['Numx','Numy']].mask(m1)
m2 = df['Code_new'] == 'BB'
df.loc[m2, ['Numx','Numy']] = df.loc[m2, ['Numx','Numy']].ffill()
print (df)
  Code  Numx  Numy Code_new
0   AA  30.2   1.9       AA
1        NaN   NaN       AA
2        NaN   NaN       AA
3   BB  35.6   2.2       BB
4       40.2   2.5       BB
5       45.5   3.1       BB
6       45.5   3.1       BB
7   CC  45.5   3.1       BB
8       45.5   3.1       BB
9   DD  42.2   5.4       BB
```

Comment: First one is spot on @jezrael. It's a bit confusing. For specific values in my dataset, I'd like to take the first value and repeat that until another event. While other events only require one row and then `nans`.

Comment: @Maxibon - Glad can help!

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. My dataset was a bit more complex than I originally posted. I was returning too many `NaN's` with your code. I tried making a new column but then I'd have to copy those values in. Will your code work if I add all the values in `isin` and then apply those to the mask function. So have `mask = df['Code_new'] == 'A1-,B1-,C1-'` ect?

Comment: @Maxibon - Do you think `df['Code_new'].isin(['A1-','B1-','C1-'])` ? Maybe best is create new question, if more complicated problem. thank you.

Comment: No worries @jezrael

Comment: It's posted under  `Conditional fill of columns in a pandas df `